# Difference between load, query and getItem operations on DynamoDB table

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

What is difference between load , query and getItem operations on a dynamoDB table . Also , how to decide which one of them needs to be used ?

Looking for some in-depth answer , i couldn't find any good detailed answer which covers the differences and their use cases in very good depth .

Answer (score 1):

`Query` can read multiple items, which you must provide a partition key and optional sort key or a condition on the sort key such as `begins_with`.

`GetItem` can only get a single item where you must provide the partition AND the sort key, should one exist on the table.

`Load` is an abstraction method used by the DynamoDB Mapper which does an underlying `GetItem`